# Appium automation testing giving me some errors

Tags: python, android, selenium-webdriver, appium, device

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\DaniThomas\PycharmProjects\python_selenium_automation\vyuwebapp_automation.py", line 26, in <module>
    driver.get(URL)
  File "C:\Users\DaniThomas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 437, in get    
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\DaniThomas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 425, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\DaniThomas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py", line 30, in check_response
    raise wde
  File "C:\Users\DaniThomas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py", line 26, in check_response
    super().check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\DaniThomas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: URI and package arguments are required
Stacktrace:
UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: URI and package arguments are required
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Program Files\Appium Server GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Program Files\Appium Server GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:380:37)
```

Need a solution for this error

Comment: You should add code snippet, it would be easier to identify the error then